# Error with homestead up

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I following the instructions to setup homestead and homstead up return:

```
☁  ~  homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/Users/cmarfil/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead/0.2.2/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "settler_default_1419000625797_92760_1424667778246_80033", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "7", "--disk", "/Users/cmarfil/VirtualBox VMs/settler_default_1419000625797_92760_1424667778246_80033/box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /Users/cmarfil/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead/0.2.2/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the imported medium '/Users/cmarfil/VirtualBox VMs/settler_default_1419000625797_92760_1424667778246_80033/box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: Compressed image is corrupted '/Users/cmarfil/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead/0.2.2/virtualbox/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Appliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 779 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

I tested the method without composer with git clone and same result.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more information. homestead.yaml and other staff.

Comment: I added the bounty to draw some attention, however in my case it was because of the directory VirtualBox was writing to did not exists. Maybe there's a problem in your case aswel, opening VirtualBox -> Preferences shows the folder where VB writes to.

Comment: this question is clearly stale -- it's for a very old version of homestead and still unanswered. If you don't need the answer then remove the question or chose an answer so it gets off the "unanswered laravel" list.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had changed my home folders user to another username, thus changing my folder structure. In the settings of VirtualBox you can specify what folder the VMs use.

Instructions how to change that folder can be found on a post at superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/256192/how-to-move-virtualbox-files

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall virtualbox and vagrant homestead. After that use those commands on your terminal:

```
rm /Users/cmarfil/VirtualBox VMs/settler_default_1419000625797_92760_1424667778246_80033/box-disk1.vmd

rm /Users/cmarfil/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead/0.2.2/virtualbox/box-disk1.vmdk
```

Then reinstall virtualbox and vagrant homestead.

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue, after investigation I found that my C drive is running out of space.
After cleaning, I got it to run.